# How can I use Domain-based routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a simple web server running Windows 2012 with IIS. I have half a dozen domains linked to this server that are basically not in use yet. I have a few more domains which are used but they could all have various subdomains that aren't supported by any site yet. So I have a default site in IIS set to catch all incoming requests that aren't handled by any other site on the server or any other server. And it's main purpose is to show a "Page not in use yet" message.
That's easy to set up but I want these pages to be a bit more fancy. So I want to have some kind of routing based on the domain name so example.com and sub.example.com and sub.sub.example.com would all be handled by the same view, but anotherexample.com would be handled by a different view and thirdexample.com by yet another view. And any domain that is not caught by this routing system would go to the default view.
And I wonder if there's a simple way to do this. Something like `[route("example.com")]` as a controller attribute which the system would recognize as the controller for a specific domain and it's subdomains. (And the URL path can be ignored.) I don't know if something like this already exists and have used Google but found nothing yet.
I can create a custom route, of course. But this tends to result in an if-then-else situation for all potential domain names. I need to know if there's a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the URL rewrite module for IIS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: It's an option but I'm looking for a routing option in my project, not something that depends too much on the server. Each domain should be linked to it's own view and I don't want this to be a bunch of rules in IIS matching views in my code. Code only.